# How to use ADF map() function

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I need to perform a data transformation in ADF and I'm having difficulty understanding how to use the map() function in DataFlow.

In the input container, I have items with a format similar to the example below:

```
{
    "companyName": "ExampleName",
    "departmentManager": [
        {
            "supervisor": "Jhon",
            "department": "Marketing",
            "salary": "$135000"
        },
        {
            "supervisor": "Emily",
            "department": "Human Resources",
            "salary": "$135000"
        }
    ],
    "id": "123456798"
}
```

I have a container in Cosmos that I retrieve several items and apply derived column and map() to transform the departmentManager column before sending it to another container. The output format will be as follows:

```
{
    "companyName": "ExampleName",
    "departmentManager": [
        {
            "supervisor": "Jhon",
            "department": "Marketing",
            "salary": 135000
        },
        {
            "supervisor": "Emily",
            "department": "Human Resources",
            "salary": 135000
        }
    ],
    "id": "123456798"
}
```

As you can see, I am changing the type from string to long. How can I achieve this goal using the map() function?

I was trying to use the following approach:

```
map(item -> 
    {
        "supervisor": item.supervisor,
        "department": item.department,
        "salary": toLong(replace(item.salary, "$", ""))
    })
```

But I am getting this error:

[image]

I was looking at the documentation, but the example is not very helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches I have tried converting the *salary* value to long.

***Approach1*** using Copy Data/Lookup Activity of ADF and Cosmos DB query.

**Configuration for Copy Data/Lookup Activity**
[image]

**Cosmos DB Query**

```
SELECT f.companyName,ARRAY(
select c.supervisor,
c.department,
udf.convertToInt(replace(c.salary,"$","")) as salary FROM c
in f.departmentManager)as departmentManager, f.id from f
```

**Code for udf.convertToInt**

```
`function convertToInt(strNum) {return parseInt(strNum);}`;
```

**Result**

[image]

***Approach2*** using dataflow
Here is the flow I created
[image]

1. **Source1** is creating source connection with Cosmos DB account.
2. **flatten1** using this activity I have flatten the *departmentManager* structure to tabular format using configuration for *Unroll by* and *Unroll root*.

**Configuration**
[image]
**Result-/Preview**
[image]

3. **derivedColumn1** added a column *departmentManager* with expression. Here I have written the expression to convert string to long conversion.

**Code for expression**
`@(supervisor=departmentManager.supervisor, department=departmentManager.department, salary=toLong(replace(departmentManager.salary,"$","")))`

**Configuration**[image]

**Result-/Preview**
Here you can see datatype of *salary* is showing as *long*.[image]

4. **aggregate1** used this to convert flatten structure again to Json structure. Used *companyName* in for *Group by* and under *Aggregates* tab used `collect(departmentManager)` expression for *departmentManager* column.

**Configuration**

[image]

[image]
**Result-/Preview**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @RitikaNalwaya! Your suggestion to use Dataflow worked perfectly and saved me so much time and frustration. I had been struggling with this problem for days, but your answer made everything clear. Thanks again for taking the time to help me out!